# MySQL game rank statistics

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am sorry if the title is not very understandable, but I really didn't know how else I could write it.

Anyway, I have a database that has 3 columns, **Index**, **Name** and **Value**.

The **Index** is well, the index, and it auto-increments. The **Name** is a random string and the **Value** is a random number that can repeat in different rows.

What I want is the database to be organized with the index going 1, 2, 3, 4 etc, depending on the value of the **Value** column, going from the highest to the lowest.

That means that I want the first row of the table to be the row with the highest value on the **Value** column and so on. And even if I add new rows with random values on the **Value** column I want it to auto-organize, switching indexes if necessary. Can that be accomplished in any way or could I do that somehow? Or is it impossible?

Comment: This is a perfect description of bad design,you probably want another computed column with user variables,a rank column

Comment: why do you want to reorganize the rows? can't you use @rownum when querying the data?

Comment: @Nimesh Lets imagine the **Value** is the money a person has. I want to show in a leaderboard on a game a TOP list of the persons depending on their wealth. That is basically the case. How would I use rownum or whatever that is to do it? I don't know a whole lot about SQL so I am going to need a bit more help then that... I didn't even understand some of the comments at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
create schema so_gibberish; -- creates database
use so_gibberish;   -- use it

create table TopScores
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,  -- whatever this is, never really defined, playerId?
    theName varchar(50) not null,
    theValue bigint not null,
    key (theValue)
);

-- truncate table TopScores;

-- create a stored procedure to insert random scores
-- creates 100 at a time when you call it

DELIMITER $$ 
drop procedure if exists insertRandomScores$$

create procedure insertRandomScores()
BEGIN
    set @i=1;
    WHILE @i<=100 DO
        insert TopScores (theName,theValue) values ('xxx',1);
        SELECT @lid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
        UPDATE TopScores SET theName=concat(
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@lid)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
            substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed)*36+1, 1)
            ), theValue=floor(rand()*384738)
        WHERE id=@lid;
        set @i=@i+1;
    END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

call insertRandomScores();  -- inserts 100 random names,scores.  Call it 10 times for 1000
select count(*) from TopScores;
-- 1000 rows

-- the above random routine was lifted from a routine to generate better random values with seeding
-- not for performance

-- Instantaneous return all players ordered by rank, showing rank in column 1:
set @rownum=0;
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank',id,theName,theValue from TopScores order by theValue desc;

-- Instantaneous return Top20 players ordered by rank, showing rank in column 1:
set @rownum=0;
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank',id,theName,theValue from TopScores order by theValue desc limit 20;

+------+-----+----------+----------+
| rank | id  | theName  | theValue |
+------+-----+----------+----------+
|    1 | 781 | BUEYKGJJ |   384685 |
|    2 | 758 | FTHGJVZZ |   384223 |
|    3 | 999 | 389IL122 |   383682 |
|    4 | 622 | NRM7J9NN |   383255 |
|    5 | 538 | 5EJB53EE |   382572 |
|    6 | 226 | BQTD6A44 |   382501 |
|    7 | 334 | YRLCI5XX |   382397 |
|    8 | 404 | UTK09NN  |   381152 |
|    9 | 885 | X6RQIP88 |   380678 |
|   10 | 292 | 71JZTMQQ |   380662 |
|   11 | 844 | FYF8ZXQQ |   380630 |
|   12 | 730 | 9O2KJYHH |   380361 |
|   13 | 770 | IHNWCL55 |   380287 |
|   14 | 861 | SL6GXH00 |   379624 |
|   15 | 399 | KE8CBRR  |   379612 |
|   16 | 597 | 8XGKB4RR |   379537 |
|   17 | 131 | 05U7C88  |   378626 |
|   18 | 865 | T30SY44  |   378503 |
|   19 | 747 | MBPC7F44 |   378181 |
|   20 | 289 | FUODJHJJ |   377817 |
+------+-----+----------+----------+
```

### Getting a Single User Rank

```
-- The main difficulty is that the OP wants the rank in column 1, regardless of even the
-- soon to be mentioned 'getting just one user' aspect. 
-- Order by is simple without any of this.

-- But later if you just want to do a search on player named "Catfish" and want his rank
-- for any particular statistic, it must have some sense of a rank # based on all users.
-- It is therefore necessary to run thru all the players even tho you want one. We run thru all players
-- to get rankings and house them in a report table if you will. So we create a report table.
-- In a complicated statistical model, a row could exist for every user with statistics on that row
-- for all the categories. Here we are saving just one statistic, theValue

-- Create a report table once or whenever. Periodically update it. 
-- Note on EA Battlefield the update occurs after each game, (some games last an hour). 
-- Stackoverflow updates its tag statistics near the end of the day.

-- so create, insert, update this table below whenever you want (cron, mysql create event, etc)
-- every minute if you want

-- Ok, so we are looking for just player 'Catfish'

update TopScores set theName='Catfish' where id=500;

-- note below the index on theName so the id above is irrelevant. no stacked deck here.

select count(*) from TopScores where theName='catfish'; -- sanity check

-- drop table playerRanks;
create table playerRanks
(   rankId int not null,
    id int not null, -- playerId ?
    theName varchar(50) not null,
    theValue int not null,
    key (theName)   -- this will be snappy
);

-- jam the data in there
set @rownum=0;
insert into playerRanks (rankId,id,theName,theValue)
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank',id,theName,theValue from TopScores order by theValue desc;


-- Query OK, 1000 rows affected (0.14 sec)

-- now get Catfish's rank:

select * from playerRanks where theName='catfish';
+--------+-----+---------+----------+
| rankId | id  | theName | theValue |
+--------+-----+---------+----------+
|    196 | 500 | Catfish |   310864 |
+--------+-----+---------+----------+

-- your results may vary
```

### Using Events for Automation

```
Creating an Event to run every five minutes for automation of this:

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -- enable the scheduler.
SELECT @@event_scheduler;  -- see if it is ON

CREATE EVENT evtUpdateStatistics
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 300 SECOND  -- run once every 5 minutes
    DO
      truncate table playerRanks;
      set @rownum=0;
      insert into playerRanks (rankId,id,theName,theValue)
      select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank',id,theName,theValue from TopScores order by theValue desc;
```

Other things to consider or tinker with:

- Locking the playerRanks table on getting data and event above to update it. It will be an quick lock and release guaranteeing that the table has values when a user fetches data instead of being empty because event has truncated it.
- Doing an Update primarily to playerRanks not a trunc and insert. Cram new users to system in just once with 0 values. Thereafter, it is updates.
- show processlist; -- active event scheduler shows up as User=event_scheduler
- SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -- enable the scheduler.
- DROP EVENT IF EXISTS evtUpdateStatistics; -- drops one

Comment: if you can update this to show @rownum then that should make it complete answer, based on the last comment by the user

Comment: @Drew If I had the **Name** of a row, how could I get its index depending on its **Value**? By that I mean, if I had the **Name** of the row with the highest **Value** it should give me the **Index** "1". How can I do that?

Comment: @DrewPierce Yeah, I was now thinking how I would get the **Rank** of an individual row if I had its **Name**. How would I do that?

Comment: @DrewPierce I wish I knew more about MySQL because I did not understand a thing about what you said on your three comments... I will need actual code to help or I am afraid I am not going to be able to do this

Comment: @DrewPierce Yeah, you probably didn't see my comment above, but it says: How could I get the **Rank** of an individual row if I had its **Name**? How would I do that? Example: How could I know that the **Rank** for the **Name** "af33sfd" is 7 (Reffering back to the table you made)?

Comment: @DrewPierce This is for a game that will constantly have new players joining, so this table will always be getting new rows and the table could get pretty big, could have 10, 100, 1000 rows or more. I want anyone to be able to just get the rank of any player by just knowing his name.

Comment: @DrewPierce All I need is the sql command that would allow me to get the rank of any player by using his name, is that possible?

Comment: @DrewPierce It is java.

Comment: @DrewPierce If the table has 1000 rows, that could be a lot to loop through, and I need this to be as efficient as possible, isn't there any other way?

Comment: @DrewPierce Well, wouldn't you be able to explain it a bit better or something around those lines? I would really like to solve this problem...